# Excel is corrupted when Attaching it to MailMessage C#

Tags: email, c#, attachment

I created application that generates excel file from DataTable using EPPlus library. Then I add MemoryStream instance to Attachment. Program works fine, i receive email, but when I open file, i get an error "Excel cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file".
I tried a lot of variants that have found in web but no one helped. May some one know how to fix this or another way how to send mailmassage with attachments.

```
 public void SendMail(DataTable dt)
        {
            using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(outputStream))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet");
                ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
                pck.Save();          
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("host");
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usarename", "password");

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com");
                message.Body = "File in attachments";             

                Attachment at = new Attachment(outputStream, "FileOutput.xls", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                message.Attachments.Add(at);
                message.Subject = "Test";
                client.Send(message);            

            }
        }
```

Comment: You're using EPPlus, but you create the attachment with an extension of .xls. Why? EPPlus cannot create .xls files. It can only do .xlsx, which is a different format. Fix your extension, and let me know if that resolved your issue.

Comment: @mason don't work. I am using ExchangeService and everything works fine.

Comment: Did you combine my answer with SilentTremor's? Did you try saving the file locally on the server to make sure you get a valid Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Try reset the stream to the beginning before creating the attachment

```
outputStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
```